# how to parse xml

Tags: iphone

i am having an output xml which looks something like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>   
 <apple><apple1>A</apple1></apple>
    <ball><ball1>B</ball1></ball>
    <cat><cat1>C</cat1></cat>
    <dog><dog1>D</dog1></dog>
    <ele><ele1>E</ele1></ele>
<root>
```

i am using NSXmlParser, i m confused, is tgis a gud xml structure?>//
secondly i dont knw how to parse this xml , i mean how should i write condition in parser `didSTart` and `didEndElement` ???

i m not to able properly navigate through each node, from apple to ele. i just want to assign the returned value of say apple to a string.
same for each node.

i m so confused in if / else condition.

Suggestions are always appreciated

regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to have exactly one root element, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <apple><apple1>A</apple1></apple>
    <ball><ball1>B</ball1></ball>
    <cat><cat1>C</cat1></cat>
    <dog><dog1>D</dog1></dog>
    <ele><ele1>E</ele1></ele>
</root>
```

I don't know about the specifics of the parser you are using, but this is an intrinsic XML issue.

Comment: ohk, thats why i am able to navigate to only one node.. so ur xml format should right, a root tag at top and bottom.?/  thank loannis

Comment: Correct. It is necessary for XML to work. Glad to have helped.

Comment: what about the if/else condition?? how to write that for each tag? thank loannis karamdimas

Comment: You might want to check out [ http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html ]. I think that the [ (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string ] method should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code.

```
resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

delegate methods to parse XML data

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
 NSLog(@"error occured %@",parseError);
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
 NSLog(@"Did Start Document");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
 self.currentElement = elementName;
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"] && !itemDictionary){
  self.itemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
 [itemDictionary setObject:string forKey:currentElement];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"] && itemDictionary)){
  [resultArray addObject:itemDictionary];
  currentItem = nil;
 }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
 NSLog("After parsing : %@", resultArray);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks jfalexvijay for replying can u plz tell me what is itemDictionary and currentItem ??? and how can i pass returend attrubute values to NSSTRing, thank again for replying

Answer (score 0):

itemDictionary is a NSMutableDictionary.

I have edited my previous answer. (currentItem is itemDictionary).
In this sample code, itemDictionary is to store all values with key (when we parsing the data).

itemDictionary - {
apple1 = A
ball1 = B
cat1 = C
dog1 = D
ele1 = E
}

```
//--------------------------
```

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 **<apple id='10'>**<apple1>A</apple1></apple>
    <ball><ball1>B</ball1></ball>
    <cat><cat1>C</cat1></cat>
    <dog><dog1>D</dog1></dog>
    <ele><ele1>E</ele1></ele>
<root>

In didStartElement method, you have to use below sample code.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"apple"]){
    NSString *attributeValue = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog("Attribute value : %@", attributeValue);
}
```

I hope, it will help you.